# How to apply css specific to IE9 browser

Tags: css

I am trying to add a property and it should apply only when the page opens in IE9. I am using the following css.

```
 .contents{
        width:5%;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align:left;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right:0.5%;
        padding-right:1%;
        float: left\9;
        padding-top: .5em; 
    }
```

I want to apply float property for IE 9. But it is using this property both in IE10 and IE9. How to stick this property to IE9?

Answer (score 0):

add the `:root` psuedo selector and `\0/IE9` for the certain style

For instace;

```
 :root .contents{
        width:5%;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align:left;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right:0.5%;  
        padding-right:1%;
        float: left \0/IE9;   /* IE9 */
        padding-top: .5em; 
    }
```

Will have the `float` applied only to IE9

Comment: I am using .less file to specify css. I used this statement and when I compiled I am getting 'parse error:unrecognised input'.DO i have to change the syntax?